# Create "Sprites" to Reduce iPhone App Memory

Tags: ios, image, memory, reduce

Currently my iPhone app loads all icons and buttons as .png images, which takes quite a lot of memory. Is there another format or means of loading multiple images such that the amount of memory my app uses is greatly reduced?

What particular UIImage method should I use to load the images?

Thanks!

Comment: This might seem obvious, but are you actually releasing references to the image memory you are using in your app? For example, do not invoke UIImageView imageNamed as this method caches the data at the system level. Instead, load with UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile and then drop the ref to a specific image when it is no longer used. Unless you are actually using all the button images all the time this is likely to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Disclaimer: not super familiar with iOS yet, probably won't have the best answer. But I'm somewhat more familiar with spriting, so maybe this will help.</sup>

A traditional approach which may save some memory (depending on how iOS devices process images; I'm not sure) is to concatenate your sprites into sprite sheets.

For example, instead of 16 separate 32x32 PNGs, it stores a single 128x128 PNG (4 by 4 sprites), and you display your sprites by pixel offsets. Commonly the offsets are expressed as indices, to be multiplied by 32 in a helper method to find the actual pixel offset.

Comment: Putting sprites into a sprite sheet is a runtime performance improvement only, it does not lower memory usage. In fact, a sprite sheet increases memory usage in general since all the memory for all the sprites in the sheet is allocated in ram once one of the sprites is used.